# Godot AdMob NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd

Tags: android, admob, godot

I'm trying to export and run Godot project on Android emulator, but after splash screen, it immediately crash.

I'm using ShinNil plugin (https://github.com/Shin-NiL/Godot-Android-Admob-Plugin) to display ads.

Here is the logcat message. I've tried to find this error on internet but no solutions work. Am I missing something?

Does anyone has faced this issue before, pls help me out.

```
Process: org.godotengine.xxx, PID: 9674
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd;
at shinnil.godot.plugin.android.godotadmob.Interstitial.<init>(Interstitial.java:25)
at shinnil.godot.plugin.android.godotadmob.GodotAdMob$8.run(GodotAdMob.java:394)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```